# Dynamically apply CSS in Ionic (angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I using Ionic 1 and am trying to change the background color and text color of the `ion-nav-bar` element but it does not get applied.

**Tried this in run() :**

```
 $rootScope.globalStyleVars = {

      "background-color" :  "#333333 !important",
      "font-color" : "#bce224 !important",
      "box-shadow" : "none !important"
    }
```

**Also this:**

```
$("#navBarTop").css('background-color', '#333');
```

**View**

```
  <ion-side-menu-content class="custom_menu">
    <ion-nav-bar ng-style="globalStyleVars" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced" >
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button icon ion-navicon "  menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
```

Comment: why dont you write a class with all the styles in globalStyleVars  and use ng-class instead??

Comment: It is more efficient to use style since if I update the bar and bar-header classes I want these updated across all parts of the app. So applying ng-style is better for this use case... do you know why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">

  <div ng-style='globalStyleVars'>
    text
  </div>
  <script>
    // Code goes here

    angular
      .module('myApp', [])

      .controller('testController', ['$rootScope',
        function($rootScope) {


          $rootScope.globalStyleVars = {
            'width': '20px',
            'height': '20px',
            'background-color': '#333333',
            'color': '#bce224',
            'box-shadow': 'none',
          }
        }
      ]);
  </script>

</body>


</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body class="platform-android use-material-icons" ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="testController" style="background:#ccc">
  <ion-nav-view class="background"></ion-nav-view>
  <ion-side-menu-content class="custom_menu">
    <ion-nav-bar ng-style="globalStyleVars" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button icon ion-navicon " menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <script>
    angular
      .module('myApp', [])

    .controller('testController', ['$rootScope',
      function($rootScope) {


        $rootScope.globalStyleVars = {
          'width': '200px',
          'height': '200px',
          'background-color': '#333333',
          'color': '#bce224',
          'box-shadow': 'none',
        }
      }
    ]);
  </script>


</body>











</html>
```

This might help you.

Comment: I tried this but still doesnt update. I have this format in the index.html:   <body class="platform-android use-material-icons" ng-app="starter" data-ng-controller="SettingsCtrl" style="background:#ccc">
    
    <ion-nav-view class="background"></ion-nav-view>

  </body>

Comment: I have done with whatever code you gave, please see my second snippet.